# Determining when to terminate a Jms Listener in SpringBoot when Queue has zero messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

What is the proper way, or the popular convention of deciding when to kill a listener? I can't seem to find a solid answer really anywhere. The queues I'm dealing with are IBM's MQ Queues, and I know typically that you would read until you receive a 2033 error code (my company does this in other applications) at which point you can wrap up, but for a SpringBoot Jms application what's the convention here? Once the queue is empty the listener just hangs until more messages come. I know HOW to kill it if I want, but how can I know WHEN?

As an example, here is a config for a sample project I threw together

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JmsConfig {

@Bean
protected DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory() throws JMSException {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency("1");
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new JmsErrorHandler());
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
    try {
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
}
```

and here is the listener

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

    @JmsListener(id = "myQueue", destination = "queue")
    public void processMessage(Message message) throws MQException, IOException {
        try {
            String messageString = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Besides the main class and the ErrorHandler, that is literally the whole sample project, and it will process messages. What I have done in other applications is instantiated a `MQQueue` given the queue values and just simple did `queue.getCurrentDepth()` and if I get a zero I then call on an instance of a ListenerContainerController that then calls stop  from a JmsListenerEndpointRegistry given the queues id.

Does Spring have an easy way of communication "hey your queue is now empty" or is there a way to end it after x amount of time has passed?

Comment: Why do you want to shut it down?  If you leave it running it will process new messages are they are PUT to that queue.

Comment: @JoshMc Because in this instance I process read the messages off and generate a report from what I've processed at which the queue should be purged and have nothing left. It's a daily ran process and I'm not sure if we want it set up how you described. Your comment makes me wonder if I'm using this JmsListener a little unconventionally. But the process would have to end at some point whether it runs once or stays listening correct?

Comment: Don't use a listener for that. If that is all you want use a `JmsTemplate` and read until nothing more to read. Produce the report and be done with it. A listener is intended to keep running and processing messages as they come along. You could even use Spring Batch and a `JmsItemReader` to read messages until nothing more to read.

Comment: @M.Deinum Wow. I learned something new, and apparently have been doing it wrong. I've had a code smell for quite sometime and couldn't really figure out why, and all the documentation/sources I stumbled across and answers to questions I got here (maybe I asked the wrong questions...) led me to believe a JmsListener is what I needed for this kind of process. Feel free to extract your comment to an answer and elaborate however you see fit and I can accept it, because that will be the route I go. Already have read over the documentation. Thanks for that comment.

Comment: When using this approach, be sure to use a `CachingConnectionFactory` so that the consumer is cached - it will avoid the template having to create a new consumer for each message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JmsListener` is intended to receive and process messages as they arrive on the destination. It isn't intended to read until the destination is empty and then stop, it is designed to keep running.

Instead just use a [`JmsTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) and its `receive` method to read the messages until they are done. Then process them and write a report.

Ultimately you could even create a Spring Batch job using the [`JmsItemReader`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/jms/JmsItemReader.html), this reader will read until there is nothing more to read and then it will all end. Underneath it also uses a `JmsTemplate`

What you could do then is, as you are using Spring Boot, use a cron job to daily trigger this job (which is basically done launching the jar you created). See also the reference guide of Spring Boot on how to work with [batch applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-batch-applications.html#howto-batch-applications).